# sweet alert2 - remove alert showing hideLoading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

hello I am using sweet alert2 to manage the alerts of my project when I make requests, these are my two functions, one is executed just before starting the request and the other when the request returns some response, I wanted to know if there is a way to hide the loading alert without showing another confirmation alert, because when using the `hideLoading` it shows me an alert after with a button, there are parts is that alert is necessary to show errors for example, but I want to remove it when the request is successful.

```
export const startLoadingAlert = ( content ) => {
    Swal.fire({
        title: content,
    });
    Swal.showLoading();
}

export const successLoadingAlert = ( content, iconParam ) => {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: iconParam,
        title: content,
    });
    Swal.hideLoading();
}
```